# How to check whether request is authenticated or not in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing one MVC application and authentication is done using active directory and login action is working properly.Now I want to show the logout link in layout using partial view, if the user is login for that I've created one partial view _LoginPartial in that view i want to show the logout link on the basis of whether the user is login or not.

Question:How to check user is logged-in or not?

Comment: add `[Authorize]` above the controller or action. check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: no,it won't work coz i want to allow login for every user.

Comment: problem is only with logout....I want to show the login link if the user is logged in but how to check whether the user is logged in or not .

Comment: Could you provide more details about how your Active Directory authentication is implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Within the *action*, use [Request.IsAuthenticated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Logic
}
```

And in *Razor*:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Your link here
}
```

Comment: it is not working,coz i'm doing authentication using active directory not using identity. :-(

Comment: It should not matter, inspect `User.Identity`, do you see user details?